# unoconv cannot connect or start listener without sudo

Tags: apache2, php, mysql

I'm working on a website for school on the school server. My website uses unoconv. It was working up until today for some reason. Basically what is happening is that if i run this command in the console:

```
 unoconv powerpoint.pptx
```

it gives me this error
     Error: Unable to connect or start own listener. Aborting.

however works with:

```
 sudo unoconv powerpoint.pptx
```

unoconv is 777 and ownership is www-data:www-data but it wont work through the website either.

```
 pgrep  -l 'office|writer|calc'
```

shows nothing to conflict, and:
     unoconv --listener &
doesnt solve the problem

What else should i do to investigate?

Comment: didnt exactly solve the problem, however I got the server to use it correctly which is all i need.

Answer (score 2):

@Erik Stagg, I know it is late but indeed to use unoconv with other user you can leave an open a port with sudo in another process:

```
$ sudo unoconv --listener
```

Meanwhile this process is running, you can use unoconv with a normal user:

```
$ unoconv -f docx file.doc
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem, and found this link very helpful:

> https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1610270

In a nutshell, open the `/etc/sudoers` file in your favorite editor and find this line:

```
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Add a new line just below it like so:

```
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
user.name    ALL=NOPASSWD: /path_to_your_program_bin_file
```

So to run unoconv from apache, you need something like this:

```
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
apache  ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/unoconv
```

Whether it's a good idea to have the apache user in the sudoers file is a whole other question, but also don't forget that the sudo privilege is limited to just the specific program in question. Apache can't run just anything with sudo: only the unoconv program.